# How to choose k in Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, self-learning

> Problem: In a factory, the probability of a screw being defective is p
>   = 0.015. What is the probability that a box of 100 screws does not contain a defective one?

One way to answer this problem is to use the Poisson formula the following way:

a) $P (\textrm{There are no defective screws in a box of 100}) = e^{-\lambda} \cdot \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$,
   where $\lambda = n\cdot p = 100 \cdot  0.015 = 1.5$,
k = 0.

Hence, $e^{-1.5} \cdot \frac{1.5^0}{k!} = e^{-1.5} \cdot  (1 / 1) = 0.2231$, which is the correct answer.

I am confused, however, why this problem cannot be calculated in the reverse way, by focusing on the probability that all 100 screws are good (which should be the same that none of them are defective). This is what I mean:

b) $P (\textrm{All screws are good in a box of 100}) =e^{-\lambda} \cdot \frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}$,
where $\lambda = n\cdot p = 100 \cdot  (1-0.015) = 100 \cdot 0.985 = 98.5,  
      k = 100.$

Hence, $e^{-98.5} \cdot  \frac{98.5^{100}}{ 100!} = \frac{3.678\cdot 10^{156}}{100!} = 0.039$, which is clearly not the same as **a)**.

Is there any stipulation in the Poisson formula whether $k$ stands for success or failure? If yes, then how does one know?

(The exercise is from Feller: An Introduction to probability theory and its applications, Vol.1, p- 155/d.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The Poisson distribution can be applied to systems with a large
>   number of possible events, each of which **is rare**"

*wiki, Poisson distribution*

This is not the case if $p=0.98$. Basically the random variables is binomial distributed. This variable can be approximated by the Poisson distribution if $n$ is large and $p$ is small.

If we use the binomial distribution we obtain $P(X=100)=0.985^{100}\approx 22\%$

Comment: Yes, indeed, 0.985 is *not* rare at all! I completly forgot about the big picture, when we use Poisson distribution. Thank you so much for pointing this out!

Comment: You´re welcome. But your question is somehow tricky.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @babesz  It was not obvious at the first view why using the poisson distribution works in the first case and not in the second case. In the first case  it worked and then my first conclusion was to use the poisson distribution as well in the second case-like you did. It took some time that I realized  the random variable is not poisson distributed.

Comment: Ah, I see now. It's the Feller book, full of tricky exercises :-)